# If $f(x) = -3x^3 + 2x^2$, find $f(-1)$ and $f(1/2)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I hope you can help me out

For number 8 and 9 find each value if $f(x) = -3x^3 + 2x^2$

8) $f(-1)$

9) $f(1/2)$

Comment: You have to substitute $-1$ into the formula for $f(x)$, i.e. into $-3x^3 + 2x^2$ and compute the value; the same with $1/2$.

Comment: The answer that is required here is to explain what kind of an object a function is.

Answer (score 2):

For x=-1 we write $f(-1)=-3*(-1)^3+2*(-1)^2=3+2=5$
For x=1/2 we write $f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=-3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3+2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{8}$

Answer (score 2):

If you've given some $f(x)$ and asked to find out $f(a)$

then you have to replace all $x$ by $a$ and then simplify ( If you cannot calculate ) resultant expression.

for example
if $$f(x)=-3x^3+2x^2$$
then $$f(-1)=-3(-1)^3+2(-1)^2=5$$

and $$f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=-3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3+2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{8}$$